# Form Post Action Error in Eclipse

Tags: jsp, jsf

I have 2 jsps .. The first one is the register jsp i.e(Register.jsp) which resides in (main folder of Webcontent) and the other jsp i.e(Register_worker.jsp which is in worker folder of WebContent) is supposed to act as the servlet or worker jsp. When i click the submit button it shows an error

HTTP Status 404 - /learn-ui/jsp/main/Register_worker.jsp

- type:Status report
- message:/learn-ui/jsp/main/Register_worker.jsp
- description:The requested resource is not available.

The form action is posted below.

```
<form id="form_register" 
      name="form_register" 
      method="post" 
      action="Register_worker.jsp">
```

Comment: Have you tried `action="worker/Register_worker.jsp"`?

Comment: yeh ive tried all possible permutaions and combinations

It shows the same error. Do we need to change the web.xml file in the WebContent??

Comment: Where are this form placed? If you can, show us the directory tree

Comment: WebContent/main/Register.jsp
WebContent/worker/Register_worker.jsp

is where these files reside

Comment: Try `action="../worker/Register_worker.jsp"`

Comment: @DiogoMoreira : thanks man.. that worked.. Wonder why it dint work before.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll post it as an answer, could you mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: @DiogoMoreira unfortunately u answered in chat..if u could answer as answer i would definitely mark it as correct. Thanks.
Click that answer Question at the bottom of screen and Submit your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path of `Register.jsp` isn't the same as `Register_worker.jsp`. So you'll need to change the path. This will work fine:

```
<form id="form_register" name="form_register" method="post" action="../worker/Register_worker.jsp">
```