# Eclipse, Web Tools Platform causing element not found error in JSP but everything works as expected

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I have an error in Eclipse in my JSP files.

[image]

No matter what I put as my `<form action=" ...` I get an `Element not found` error. This is on every form, on every JSP, which makes it harder to track down actual problems in my `Project Explorer` since everything has a red X on it.

My code works as expected, and I would prefer to not just disable the warning, as I'm still learning and generally appreciate error messages.

Not helpful:

[Form Post Action Error in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976277/form-post-action-error-in-eclipse)

[Eclipse jsp error in editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21774883/eclipse-jsp-error-in-editor)

[<form action="/sampleServlet" giving me exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683877/form-action-sampleservlet-giving-me-exception)

**EDIT**

Neon -v 4.6.0

Did a reinstall and figured out it is the WTP that is causing the error.

Comment: Did you tried using a `<:out />` tag ? The editor for JSP is not perfect so I am not sure this will do it

Comment: Not the solution.

Comment: Can you show the full properties of the error in the Problems View? Which version of Eclipse is this? I don't see it on Neon.1. Do you have additional validation or web plug-ins installed?

Comment: neon is still buggy try mars instead